Traveling to the US with dual citizenship (Mexican/Spanish)
I have both passports with the same name and both of them are valid.
However, to enter the US as a Mexican citizen I require a visa, I have traveled to the US before with my Spanish passport and my ESTA, with no issues, by booking my flights with the Spanish passport, and entering and leaving the us with my Spanish passport.
However recently there's this new enforcement that Mexicans should present themselves as Mexican citizens when leaving the country.
So my question is:
Can I book my flights with my Mexican passport, checking in with it, and presenting my Spanish passport and ESTA as additional documents when checking in (as to explain to the airline, that I am allowed to enter the US under my ESTA).
And THEN at US immigration present my Spanish passport and ESTA (Im assuming that their system would let them know I flew in with another passport, can this be an issue?).
Leave the US with my Spanish passport as per usual.
Would that be problematic? Does anyone have experience, leaving a country with one passport and entering the US with a different one?

This question is similar to: I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Does Mexico have exit passport control?

Are you travelling from Mexico or from another country?

For you to fly to the US with ESTA, the airline will have to put your Spanish passport into the US advance passenger information system (APIS).  That doesn't necessarily prevent them from reporting your departure to Mexican authorities with your Mexican passport data, but it's certainly possible that not all airlines' systems support this.  I would give both passports to the airline and let them worry about the details.

Do you know the administrative details of the "new enforcement"? In the US there's a law saying US citizens must "bear" a US passport on departure, but the government says that the law requires them to "use" it, even though that's not what the law says.  Like Hilmar, I have flown from the US on dozens of occasions using a foreign passport without anyone saying anything.

@phoog IME airlines are not good at handling dual nationalities, so I personally make the decision myself which passport to give and when. Also the check-in APIS info entry almost always allows only one passport. You'd have to check-in at airport which is risky and sometimes paid.

@jcaron No, but with a Spanish passport the airline is required to collect an FMM as a precondition for letting you board. OP should present the Spanish passport first, and when asked for an FMM, respond by also showing the Mexican passport

I'm dual German & US. When travelling from Germany to the US I present my German passport when I leave Germany and my US passport when I enter the US. I use the US passport at check in (since the airline needs to check your ability to enter the destination country).
So the exact order for your trip is:

Flight booking: either passport
Checking in: Spanish passport
Mexican exit immigration: Mexican passport
US entry immigration: Spanish passport

So unless there is something specifically different about Mexican rules, this should work for you just fine.

Don't you mean that you use the US passport at check-in for a trip from Germany to the US?

@phoog: yes, of course. Thanks for catching this. Fixed

@Hilmar 1. is wrong; it's imperative that OP submit APIS based on their Spanish passport details

@Crazydre: what specifically is wrong? I don't understand your point. APIS data is submitted by the airlines and hence the OP should indeed use their Spanish passport for check as stated in step 2

@Hilmar You wrote "Flight booking: either passport", whereas in fact the Spanish passport needs to be used for that

@Crazydre: passport used at booking doesn't matter. You can always present a different one at check in. The check-in passport is used for APIS.

When checking in online for the flight, provide your Spanish passport details. Same when submitting APIS.
If having heavy luggage and needing to go to bag drop, present your Spanish passport there, and if they ask for an FMM, also present your Mexican passport.
At the gate, present your Spanish passport. If you don't go to bag drop you may be asked for an FMM at the gate; again present your Mexican passport in that case.
